# How do I serialize video frames for streaming over UDP?

Tags: python, serialization, udp, pickle

I am trying out video streaming over UDP. I capture my screen using vidgear and use pickle for serialization. I am trying to build a remote desktop solution therefore requiring low-latency, but I found that pickle is slow for the purpose.
Are there any other serialization frameworks that can serialize video frames?
I was able to find ****flatbuffers**** and ****protobuf**** but I am not sure how to use these for video.

So it would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction, i.e suggest a fast  serialization framework.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: do you really have to serialize it ? Frame should be only `bytes` which may need only header (one or two bytes) with number of `bytes` - so when client will read it then first it should get information how many bytes it has to read, and later it should read these bytes.

Comment: it seems `vidgear` gives frame as `numpy.array` and it can gives you it as bytes - `arr.tobytes()` and you could send it - but at the beginning you should add some with information - ie. frame width and height, number of bytes. You can convert integer to 4 bytes using `struct`. It this [example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/socket-send-receive-image) I get image from pygame, convert to bytes, add number of bytes in image (always as 4 bytes) and send it to client. Client read 4 bytes, convert to integer, and read all needed bytes.

Comment: @furas I read somewhere that pickle is slow. So does this mean the numpy function `arr.tobytes()` is faster?

Comment: `tobytes()` doesn't serialize it - it only gives you raw data as bytes. It doesn't add any extra info to this like type of data  but this should be always the same type so you can set it directly in client code. You have to add only length of data - ie `struct.pack('I', len(arr))` Besides, for array 3x3 (which means 9 values) with `dtype=np.uint8` pickle gives me 159 bytes, and `tobytes()` gives only 9 bytes. If I add `struct.pack('I', len(arr))` to `tobytes()` then it will be 13 bytes. And numpy may use C/C++ code for this so it may works faster - but I don't see difference for small data.

Comment: @guidingfox hey, author of vidgear here. Can you please raise this issue here https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/issues/new/choose, I'll see what can be done to improve the performance. Also, Are you using [WriteGear](https://abhitronix.github.io/vidgear/latest/gears/writegear/introduction/) for UDP streaming or some third-party library?

Comment: Hey @furas Thank you for the response. I've successfully implemented the `tobytes()` function.

Comment: Hey @abhiTronix I am using the socket library for this purpose. However I didn't know about `WriteGear`  will certainly look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you already resolved it but meanwhile I made some example.

You can use `tobytes()` to convert `numpy.arraay` to `bytes` which you can send by socket.

```
    byte_data = arr.tobytes()
```

You can also use `struct` to convert values its length to `4 bytes` or `height,width,depth` to `12 bytes`

```
    size = len(byte_data)
    byte_size = struct.pack('I', size)

    width, height, depth = arr.shape
    byte_width_height = struct.pack('III', width, height, depth)
```

And then you can send with size or with `width, height, depth`

```
    all_bytes = byte_size + byte_data
    send(all_bytes)

    all_bytes = byte_height_width + byte_data
    send(all_bytes)
```

In client you can first get `4 bytes` with size

```
byte_size = recv(4)

size = struct.unpack('I', byte_size)
```

or `12 byes` if you send it with `height,width,depth`

```
byte_height_width_depth = recv(12)

height, width, depth = struct.unpack('III', byte_height_width_depth)
```

and then you know how may bytes has frame

```
byte_data = recv(size)

arr = np.frombuffer(byte_data, dtype=np.uint8)
```

with `height,width,depth` you may know also how to reshape it

```
byte_data = recv(height*width*depth)

arr = np.frombuffer(byte_data, dtype=np.uint8)
arr = arr.reshape((height, width, depth))
```

---

If you use frame always with the same `height, width, depth` then you could send only data without `height, width, depth` or even without `size and use hardcoded values in code.

But if you plan to send it as compressed to JPG or PNG which may have different number of bytes then you will need to send size as first value.

---

Using `pickle` you get more bytes because it send information about class `numpy.array` to reconstruct it.

Using `tobytes` you have to reconstruct array on your own.

---

Example code - it simulate to `send`, `recv`.

```
import numpy as np
import struct
import pickle


"""Simulater socket."""
internet = bytes()
pointer = 0


def send(data):
    """Simulater socket send."""
    global internet
    
    internet += data
    
def recv(size):
    """Simulater socket recv."""
    global pointer

    data = internet[pointer:pointer+size]    
    pointer += size
    
    return data

    
def send_frame(arr):
    #height, width, depth = arr.shape
    #byte_height_width_depht = struct.pack('III', width, height, depth)
    byte_height_width_depht = struct.pack('III', *arr.shape)
    #send(byte_height_width_depht)
    
    byte_data = arr.tobytes()
    #send(byte_data)
    
    all_bytes = byte_height_width_depht + byte_data
    send(all_bytes)

    print('all_bytes size:', len(all_bytes))
    print('all_bytes data:', all_bytes)

def recv_frame():
    byte_height_width_depht = recv(12)

    height, width, depth = struct.unpack('III', byte_height_width_depht)

    byte_data = recv(height*width*depth)

    arr = np.frombuffer(byte_data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((height, width, depth))

    return arr
    
# --- main ---    

arr = np.array([
        [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
        [[255,   0,   0], [  0,   0, 255]],
        [[255,   0,   0], [  0,   0, 255]],
        [[255, 255, 255], [255, 255, 255]],
], dtype=np.uint8)

print('--- pickle ---')

data = pickle.dumps(arr) 
print('pickle size:', len(data))
print('pickle data:')
print(data)
print()

arr = pickle.loads(data)
print('array:')
print(arr)
print()

print('--- send frame ---')
send_frame(arr)
print()

print('--- recv frame ---')
arr = recv_frame()
print(arr)
print()
```